# Incrementally convert a React Native Javascript + flow project to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a large React Native project written with Javascript + flow, and would like to convert it to Typescript. This is something I've wanted to do for a while, but haven't got around to doing it because of the painful process of fixing ALL the files, which will take me a very long time.

Is there a way to incrementally introduce Typescript into my project by updating one file at a time? In other words, is it possible to have a React Native project that builds with Javascript and Typescript components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add typescript little by little.. Use `// @ts-ignore` to ignore typescript compiler for the code that break. Then start remove the `// @ts-ignore` as you transform your code from javascript to typescript.